# Get values from selected box in bs dual list angularJS

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to get the selected values in a dual box. 
with refference of this link http://www.virtuosoft.eu/code/bootstrap-duallistbox/

I have done something like below code snippet:

**.html**

```
<select name="duallistbox_demo1[]"
                        ng-model="recSchedule"

                        ng-options="recSchedule as recSchedule.recSchedulingName for recSchedule in recordingSchedules"
                        size="10"
                        multiple
                        bs-duallistbox
                        selected-list-label="{{ settings.selectedListLabel }}"
                        non-selected-list-label="{{ settings.nonSelectedListLabel }}">
                </select>
```

**json file:**

```
[

    {
        "id": "1",        
        "recSchedulingName": "Record Schedule 1"
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "recSchedulingName": "Record Schedule 2"
    },
    {
        "id": "3",
        "recSchedulingName": "Record Schedule 3"
    }
]
```

**.js**

```
console.log($('[name="duallistbox_demo1[]"]').val());
```

I am getting only this:

```
["object:326"]
```

I need to show the id or recSchedulingName here.

Comment: bootstrap with angular or a custom bootstrap+angular?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the code you have written `console.log($('[name="duallistbox_demo1[]"]').val());` is a node js code. This is not compatible with angualrjS.

All data you can get from object ng-model="recSchedule". You can put this object in a foreach and see the values.